# Cross-compile Qt5 applications in Beaglebone Black Board

Tags: cross-compiling, beagleboneblack, qt5.5

```
gcc --version

gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

root@beaglebone:~# gcc --version
gcc (Debian 4.6.3-14) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Which 'arm-linux-gnueabihf' toolchain and Qt opensource version is required. Host is Ubuntu 16.04 with Qt5.10.

Answer (score 0):

Download QT from https://www.qt.io/ for linux, then install a debian toolchain which matches with you target board. Include your toolchain in QT then you can start cross compiling apps for QT